# Arity constraint on Julialang function type

Tags: function, types, julia

Is it possible to specify a type constraint on arity of a Julia function, something like:

```
function foo(bar::Function{1})
  ...
end
```

This definition gives me an error:

```
ERROR: too many parameters for type Function
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking is not possible, since a Julia function does not have well-defined arity.

Consider

```
f(x) = "method 1"
f(x, y) = "method 2"
```

after which `f` may be invoked in two ways:

```
julia> f(0)
"method 1"

julia> f(0, 0)
"method 2"
```

What, then, is the arity of `f`? If you are seeking to change behaviour of the function depending on its arity, then you need to pass in the desired arity as an additional parameter. Otherwise, the arity check can probably be left out.

Comment: First case : arity = 1, second case arity = 2. The important part is the signature, not the computation.

Comment: This one would not be as easy as mrdivide :)

Comment: @ArtemOboturov: Because of [multiple dispatch](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/methods/), `f` is a single function with two methods defined. It has one method with arity 1, and one method with arity 2, but `f` itself has no well-defined arity. The exact computation done is unimportant. I have edited it to remove the computation itself.

Comment: May be I miss something? `f(x)` is an object of type `F{1}`, `f(x, y)` is an object of type `F{2}`. They both happen to have the same name, `f`. This is something which is not forbidden by Julia. Multiple dispatch would just be resolving name `f` to an instance. How a type constraint could make it fail?

Comment: @ArtemOboturov You are talking about the methods of `f`, not the function itself. `f` is inseparable; the dispatch is resolved at runtime, hence dynamic dispatch. To obtain a particular method from `f`, the `which` function must be called: `which(f, (Int, Int))`, but this precludes knowing the desired arity already.

Answer (score 3):

Most probably, the arity constraint is needed to ensure parameter correctness. This does not need to be done in the function signature, but can be done using parameter checks at the top of the function code. One method could be:

```
if !any(m->length(m.sig.parameters)==2, methods(bar))
  error("bar must be callable with 2 parameters")
end
```

More detailed checks on the signature of `bar` are also possible.

The declared parameter types of the function `foo` are idiomatically used to direct optimization through type inference and multiple dispatch and less to validate parameters.

Note that using the internal structure of MethodTable and Method types is not official Julia spec and might be subject to change in future versions of Julia.

Comment: that's looks a lot like R or Matlab. The whole point to have a static type system is to be able to handle such constraints on the level of the type system.

Comment: Julia is an interpreted (albeit, with pre-compilation) language. This means, Types are assigned and defined as the program runs. The parameter constraints help in choosing specifically optimized versions of functions to call (and initially compile). And yeah, it does look like R or Matlab because they are interpreted as well. Incidentally, even if the arity constraints existed, one would then ask: *why not limit the whole signature of parameter function?* - the check suggested gives the same effect with no overhead and in a perfect world such checks would not be necessary anyway.

Comment: Having said that, instead of passing a generic Function, you can pass a custom type which would support this requirement on a call method. This is related to the Traits tricks by Mauro and Tim Holy. This could result in some speed benefit, but it might to go with the interpreted check in the Answer. (see https://github.com/mauro3/Traits.jl).

Comment: @DanGetz I wouldn't go so far as calling Julia an interpreted language, as it always compiles down to native code (although I believe there is work going on to add interpretation of the AST in Julia, instead of always compiling). (I've also worked before on a number of languages that really were interpreted).  You do need to be aware of just when that compilation occurs, esp. with macros, which can be tricky, just what happens when the macro itself is compiled, and when it is used during the compilation of code elsewhere.

Comment: The distinction you make (about how types are assigned and defined dynamically) is really the distinction between dynamic vs. statically typed language, as opposed to interpreted vs. compiled. (and there is also the distinction between strong vs. weak typing).  Julia IMO is a strongly & dynamically typed compiled language.

Comment: Whether Julia is interpreted or compiled is irrelevant. There are statically typed interpreted languages and dynamically typed compiled languages.

The relevant bit is that Julia functions work on dynamic dispatch, and so they have no well-defined arity. The same function could have a two-argument form for some particular combination of types but not for others.